# XSL : Transform for some element remaining have to display as it is

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

i Need to merge Company code to order number.I need a XSLT to solve the below problem.
Please help me on this.

Input XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ImportOrders>
  <OrderInfo>
    <OrderNumber>98947</OrderNumber>
    <HeaderInfo>
      <CompanyCode>TEST</CompanyCode>
    </HeaderInfo>
  </OrderInfo>
  <OrderInfo>
    <OrderNumber>98949</OrderNumber>
    <HeaderInfo>
      <CompanyCode>GIM</CompanyCode>   
  </OrderInfo> 
</ImportOrders>
```

OUTPUT XML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ImportOrders>
  <OrderInfo>
    <OrderNumber>TEST-98947</OrderNumber>
    <HeaderInfo>
      <CompanyCode>TEST</CompanyCode>
    </HeaderInfo>
  </OrderInfo>
  <OrderInfo>
    <OrderNumber>GIM-98949</OrderNumber>
    <HeaderInfo>
      <CompanyCode>GIM</CompanyCode>   
  </OrderInfo> 
</ImportOrders>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved quite elegantly by using the [identity transform](https://dh.obdurodon.org/identity.xhtml) pattern and adding an additional template for the `OrderNumber`.

The following template just copies the input to the output verbatim:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/|@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now you add a template for `OrderNumber` selecting the value and the corresponding `CompanyCode`

```
<xsl:template match="OrderNumber">
    <OrderNumer>
        <xsl:value-of select="../HeaderInfo/CompanyCode"/>-<xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </OrderNumer>
</xsl:template>
```

Here's the working solution in a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-q-60811822-pdk2j

Note that in your example, the closing `HeaderInfo` tag for the second `OrderInfo` is missing, I guess this is just a typo.